# How to measure voice frequency range in Hz?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, tools, voice-recognition

I want to measure the voice frequency in Hz. Is there any open source or tool available in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5):

This list is by no means exhaustive:

[**Spek**](http://spek.cc/) - helps to analyse your audio files by showing their spectrogram. Perhaps the easiest for novice users and available from the Software Centre.

[**Audacity**](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) - the reference audio editor for Linux, but with a complex user interface; also available from the Software Centre.

[**JAAA**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com) - audio signal generator and spectrum analyser designed to make accurate measurements; available from the Software Centre.

[**Spectrum3d**](http://spectrum3d.sourceforge.net/) - an audio spectrum analyser in 3D for Linux; works in real time from the mic or in non-real time from an audio file.

[**Toscanalyzer**](http://www.toscanalyzer.org/index.php/en/menu-product-information-eng) - among many other features: frequency band analysis on 4 bands and sub-band;
frequency band distribution in stereo space; representation of spectrum with frequency and tonal scaling.

[**SoundRuler**](http://soundruler.sourceforge.net/main/) - a tool for measuring and graphing sound and for teaching acoustics.

**[Spectrum Analyzer](http://www.qsl.net/dl4yhf/spectra1.html)** - an oldie programmed for DOS that is supposed to run on Wine.

Comment: i am asking the speaking frequency. ie., i am recording my voice using mic. i saved this file, might be mp3 or wav format. i get the frequency range from this stored file. how to i get it?

Comment: I do not fully understand, once you have the spectrogram what else do you wish to get?

Comment: I am trying to measure the pitch of a human voice. I believe it is measured in frequencies. So how do I measure the frequency of a human voice? Do I record a person reciting the vowels in their regular voice? How do I label the voice as low, medium, high pitch based on the frequencies?

Comment: These later questions of yours are not related to any software, much less to Ubuntu. I recommend the [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com) site for that matter.

Answer (score 4):

A lightweight application which does just this is [lingot](http://lingot.nongnu.org/).

[image: lingot, G# tone]

Note: `lingot` supports OSS, ALSA, and JACK. It has supported OSS since first release and JACK and ALSA since version 0.8.0 (2010-02-26).

Other options:

- [fmit - Free Music Instrument Tuner](http://gillesdegottex.github.io/fmit)
- [gtkguitune - Guitar and other instruments tuner](https://web.archive.org/web/20091026230436/http://geocities.com/harpin_floh/kguitune_page.html)
- [gxtuner - Tuner for Jack](https://guitarix.sourceforge.io)
- [zita-at1 - JACK autotuner](http://kokkinizita.linuxaudio.org/linuxaudio/)